# QuickFix/n - MDStreamID

Tags: c#, quickfix, fix-protocol, financial, trading

I'm trying to develop a FIX Client for the first time in C#.NET (with [QuickFIX/n](http://quickfixn.org/tutorial/example-applications.html)) using ESP (Executable Streaming Prices), however i'm receiving a **Market Data Request Reject** with the following text in **tag 58**:

> 58=Stream [DEV_px.123]  invalid venuestream symbol [test EUR/USD]

`DEV_px` is my `SenderCompID`, `123` is my `MDReqID` (tag 262), `test` is my `MDStreamID` (tag 1500), and `EUR/USD` is the currency pair for `Symbol` (tag 55) inside `NoRelatedSymGroup` (tag 146).

For some reason, it looks like both `MDStreamID` and `NoRelatedSymGroup` are being combined. I reviewed the structure for a [Market Data Request](https://www.onixs.biz/fix-dictionary/4.2/msgType_V_86.html) but it doesn't show any tag for `MDStreamID`. This is required by my organization as an "*identifier of the price stream*" (provided by my organization).

**Here are the relevant messages that are being sent/received to and from the server**:

`<outgoing> 8=FIX.4.4☺9=135☺35=V☺34=2☺49=DEV_px ☺52=20170830-13:29:49.465☺56=COMPANY_DEV☺262=123☺263=1☺264=0☺265=0☺1500=test☺146=1☺55=EUR/USD☺64=20170831☺267=1☺269=0☺10=089☺`

`<incoming> 8=FIX.4.4☺9=134☺35=Y☺34=2☺49=COMPANY_DEV☺52=20170830-13:29:49.405☺56=DEV_px☺58=Stream [DEV_px.123]  invalid venuestream symbol [test EUR/USD]☺262=123☺10=058☺`

**Here is the relevant code snippet**:

```
QuickFix.FIX44.MarketDataRequest espRequest = new QuickFix.FIX44.MarketDataRequest(
    new MDReqID("123"),
    new SubscriptionRequestType('1'),
    new MarketDepth(0)
);

espRequest.SetField(new MDUpdateType(0));
espRequest.SetField(new MDStreamID("test"));

// Add the NoRelatedSym group
var relatedSymbols = new QuickFix.FIX44.MarketDataRequest.NoRelatedSymGroup();
relatedSymbols.SetField(new Symbol("EUR/USD"));
relatedSymbols.SetField(new SettlDate("20170831"));
espRequest.AddGroup(relatedSymbols);

// Add the NoMDEntries group
var mdEntries = new QuickFix.FIX44.MarketDataRequest.NoMDEntryTypesGroup();
mdEntries.SetField(new MDEntryType('0'));
espRequest.AddGroup(mdEntries);

Session.SendToTarget(espRequest, app.GetSessionId());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: I needed to use the DataDictionary file that my organization provided as opposed to the one downloaded from the web (FIX44.xml) which lacked MDStreamID apparently. I also chose the incorrect venue for the MDStreamID tag.

After doing those two things, I'm receiving a Market Data Snapshot Full Refresh as intended!

Edit: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25858091/quickfix-failing-to-read-repeating-group?rq=1) SO question and answer helped me to identify that my tags were not being read correctly and then I started digging further into my DD.

Comment: Good work!  As a general rule of thumb, NOBODY uses the default DataDictionary.  Every counterparty screws with it at least a little bit.  Always read their docs, and always make sure your DD matches!