# Quickfix data dictionary problem - repeating group error

Tags: python, quickfix, fix-protocol

I am using Quickfix to connect to CTS and I'm having the same exact problem as @Wapiti experienced in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25858091/quickfix-failing-to-read-repeating-group).

Whenever I turn on the DataDictionary and direct to the location of my DataDictionary file, I am unable to Logon to CTS.

Whenever I turn off the DataDictionary, I succeed logging onto CTS but I get the same error that @Wapiti posted:

Event log: Message 3 Rejected: Tag appears more than once:269

Message log: 20190307-19:38:54.000000000 : 8=FIX.4.29=10435=334=549=XXXX52=20190307-19:38:54.00056=CTS45=558=Tag appears more than once371=269372=W10=005

Tag 269 is MDEntryType and it should be a repeating group. I realize my problem probably has to do with the configuration of my data dictionary. I tried switching from 'DataDictionary=...' to 'AppDataDictionary=...' as Steve recommended in the thread linked to above but that didn't resolve the problem.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to provide what exactly you have within your Data Dictionary, so it is easier to see where you are going wrong.

By using the information that you have given, I presume your Data Dictionary looks like this?

```
<group name="NoMDEntryTypes" required="N">      
    </group>
```

However the MDEntryType should be within a repeating group called NoMDEntryTypes like below.

```
 <group name="NoMDEntryTypes" required="N">
            <field name="MDEntryType" required="N"/>
    </group>
```

Comment: Can you please write more on how this works, what the underlying problem is, and why this fixes it?